# how to set validation and filter field in Slick like lift-mapper

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I'am newbie for Slick 3 and I want to know how to set validation and filter in slick 3 like lift-mapper

something like trim a string or validate a length of string when I insert or update data into slick 3

Thank you

Comment: and what have you tried?

Comment: I want trim a string and validate a length of string when I insert or update data, I tried MappedColumnType but it didn't work